# PHP MYSQL - select high score winner

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming we have a table like below

```
   id   |   name   |  userid  |  score  |      date      |
   ------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   john   |    1     |   44    |  2013-03-2 
    2   |   mary   |    2     |   59    |  2013-03-5  
    3   |   john   |    1     |   38    |  2013-03-8 
    4   |   elvis  |    3     |   19    |  2013-03-10 
    5   |   john   |    1     |   100   |  2013-03-11
```

I want to select four winner of last week.week start Sunday to Sunday.
also i want to select one winner of a month.

winner have highest score.

i use this code for weekly winner

```
SELECT winner.id,winner.score FROM winner WHERE winner.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND winner.date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY ORDER BY winner.score DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Also monthly winner

```
SELECT winner.id,winner.score FROM winner WHERE  MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(winner.date) ORDER BY winner.score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

both are give wrong results

Comment: hmm, Ok. so do you have some code to share? – any ideas ? even some trial & error is oK

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks research effort

Comment: John will definately be the winner!

Comment: i add my query @Coffee

Comment: i add my query in question @ZachSpencer

Comment: what is the response? how is it wrong?

Comment: it return  4 item order by DESC not depend on high score @ZachSpencer

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want the result to be `john, mary, john, john` or `john, mary, elvis`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select id ,score  
 from winner
 where DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') between date_sub(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
 ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 4

 -------------------

 SELECT id,score FROM winner 
 WHERE  MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date) 
 ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Make sure that your example data will not work because they are 2013 !!

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f722/3)